# I am not able to get Fuel level from nissan models through OBD. What are my option if i need to get the fuel level

Tags: can-bus, obd-ii

I see that in various nissan models, Fuel level is not supported in OBD. However the dashboard does show fuel level. How are they showing it? Is it some manufacture specific PID that is used?
If i need to show fuel level to my customer, what are my options?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because there is no programming problem to be solved. How/where to find OBD documentation isn't an on-topic question here.

Answer (score 1):

It is not necessary that the fuel level information goes to the dashboard only through OBD. Mostly this information will be going via some CAN frames. If you have the network description file of the CAN Bus, then you can identify which CAN ID carries this information and how to decode this.

Comment: Yes, No PID with respect to  fuel level. Checked this using external can logistics tool as well

Comment: If this answer cleared your query, please do consider marking this as the answer using the tick mark on the left side.